Plotting solution of a three body problem with given initial conditions
Disclaimer:I am not trying to find new solutions for the 3 body problem (3bp), I already have the initial conditions and I already know what configuration I should get.
I am trying to create an animation with the orbits of a 3bp system with given initial conditions. Before going over the animation I'm trying to just plot the solutions.
So far I was able to solve the system of differential equations, however I cannot plot it. Here it is what I've done so far:
c1 = 0.1546025015193900;
c2 = -0.0987561640960160;
c3 = -1.1843704912618038;
c4 = 0.2521819944674475;
x1 = -2 c1; x2 = c1; x3 = c1;
y1 = 0;
y2 = c2;
y3 = -c2;
vx1 = 0;
vx2 = c3;
vx3 = -c3;
vy1 = -2 c4;
vy2 = c4;
vy3 = c4;
m1 = 1;
m2 = 1;
m3 = 1;
G = 1;
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{
   r1''[t] == -G (m2 (r1[t] - r2[t])/Abs[r1[t] - r2[t]]^3 + 
       m3 (r1[t] - r3[t])/Abs[r1[t] - r3[t]]^3),
   r2''[t] == -G (m3 (r2[t] - r3[t])/Abs[r2[t] - r3[t]]^3 + 
       m1 (r2[t] - r1[t])/Abs[r2[t] - r1[t]]^3),
   r3''[t] == -G (m1 (r3[t] - r1[t])/Abs[r3[t] - r1[t]]^3 + 
       m2 (r3[t] - r2[t])/Abs[r3[t] - r2[t]]^3),
   r1[0] == Sqrt[x1^2 + y1^2], r2[0] == Sqrt[x2^2 + y2^2], 
   r3[0] == Sqrt[x3^2 + y3^2],
   r1'[0] == Sqrt[vx1^2 + vy1^2], r2'[0] == Sqrt[vx2^2 + vy2^2], 
   r3'[0] == Sqrt[vx3^2 + vy3^2]},
  {r1[t], r2[t], r3[t]}, {t, 0, 10},]

This code runs smoothly, with no issues at all (apparently). I tried several different ways to plot it, but here are the two that seems the most resonable:
Plot[Evaluate[{r1[t], r2[t], r3[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}]

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{r1[t], r2[t], r3[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All]

None of them are working and I cannot figure out why.
PS: c1, c2, c3, and c4 are constants related to the initial conditions of each mass.

You are using ParametricNDSolve but not giving it any parameters either in solving or in applying the solution. I think that is bad. Look at the examples in the documentation and see if you can see what I mean. If there are no parameters then perhaps NDSolve would be more appropriate.

You also have what look like some zero denominators whenever your Abs[r2[t] - r3[t]] is zero

I tried using NDSolve, but I only get several errors. I tried to increase the precision, decrease the steps and everything else, but I couldn't get a solution. Using ParametricNDSolve was the only method that I found to run the code.

Your code doesn't run, check the initial conditions which seem to be Indeterminate

NBodySimulation might be relevant to you

@I.M. thank you very much, that's what I needed. Should I delete this post or do I leave it as it is?

There is no reason to delete it. It might help people, who missed on build in function, asking similar questions to find it. You can also post a self answer.

Thanks to @I.M.'s reply, here it follows the code that worked for me:
c1 = 0.1546025015193900;
c2 = -0.0987561640960160;
c3 = -1.1843704912618038;
c4 = 0.2521819944674475;
c5 = 0.5587063079197599;
x1 = -2 c1; x2 = c1; x3 = c1;
y1 = 0; y2 = c2; y3 = -c2;
vx1 = 0; vx2 = c3; vx3 = -c3;
vy1 = -2 c4; vy2 = c4; vy3 = c4;
m1 = 1/3; m2 = 1/3; m3 = 1/3;
tf = 3 c5;
data = NBodySimulation["InverseSquare",
  {
   "M1" -> <|"Mass" -> m1, "Position" -> {x1, y1}, 
     "Velocity" -> {vx1, vy1}|>,
   "M2" -> <|"Mass" -> m2, "Position" -> {x2, y2}, 
     "Velocity" -> {vx2, vy2}|>,
   "M3" -> <|"Mass" -> m3, "Position" -> {x3, y3}, 
     "Velocity" -> {vx3, vy3}|>
   }, tf]
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[data[All, "Position", t]], {t, 0, tf}]
names = {"M1", "M2", "M3"};
ListAnimate[
 Table[Graphics[Map[Text[#, data[#, "Position", t]] &, names], 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 0.5}, {-.2, 0.2}}], {t, 0, tf, 1}]]

